# How to transfer AWS Lightsail snapshots across accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have built a WordPress website on AWS Lightsail and I need to transfer it to a different AWS account.

What is the recommended approach?

I'm thinking of the following approach

1. Create a Lightsail snapshot
2. Copy to EC2
3. Take a snapshot of EC2 and share it a different account as mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-account-copying-of-encrypted-ebs-snapshots/)

Isn't there a way to share Lighsail Snapshots directly across accounts ?

Comment: I was looking for a similar solution but it appears that AWS doesn't offer any solution for transferring the snapshots across the accounts. On the other hand, it is still possible to get an image of the LS instance manually and then install the same image to the other account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently had the same problem. Seems like in 2023, there's still no way to directly transfer a Lightsail instance from one AWS account to another.

What did it for me was exporting a Lightsail snapshot to EC2 and sharing the image with my target account. I documented the process [here](https://medium.com/@iggyblob/how-to-transfer-an-amazon-lightsail-instance-to-another-aws-account-56136c407f8a).

Answer (score 4):

That functionality was not available on FEB 2020 (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=316405)
and still from my research there is no way to do so...